# RSForms - local storage in combination with database storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I found this JavaScript that saves values of rsforms fields as local storge in the browser.
It works fine - but it overrides the data that are stored in the database.

I need a solution to edit the data the users stored in the database and when they change the values, these new values should be stored localy until the user presses the submit button - for storage in the database.

Here the javascript but this overrides my data of the database:

$('document').ready(function(){

```
    $('input[type="text"], textarea').each (
        function(index){  
            var field = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).val($.cookie(field));
        }
    );

    $('input[type="radio"]').each(
        function(index){  
            var field = $(this).attr("name");
            if($.cookie(field)) {
                var value = $.cookie(field);
                $("[id='"+value+"']").prop('checked',true);
            }
        }
    );

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(
        function(index){  
            var field = $(this).attr("name");
            if($.cookie(field)) {
                var value = $.cookie(field);
                $("[id='"+value+"']").prop('checked',true);
            }
        }
    );

    $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('input', function() {
        var Uniq = $(this).attr("id");
        var Content = $(this).val();
        $.removeCookie(Uniq);
             $.cookie(Uniq, Content);
    });

    $('input:radio').on('change', function() {
        var Uniq = $(this).attr("name");
        var Content = $(this).attr("id");
        $.removeCookie(Uniq);
            $.cookie(Uniq, Content);
    });


    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        var Uniq = $(this).attr("name");
        var Content = $(this).attr("id");
        $.removeCookie(Uniq);
            $.cookie(Uniq, Content);
    }); 
});
```